# What can help decrease outliers' influence on non-tree models?

Tags: preprocessing, outlier, ranking

I have a feature with all the values between 0 and 1 except few outliers larger than 1. I am trying to collect all the methods that can help to decrease outliers' influence on non-tree models:

- StandardScaler
- Apply rank transform to the features
- Apply `np.log1p(x)` transform to the data
- MinMaxScaler
- Winsorization

I wasn't able to imagine any other ... I guess that's all?

Comment: There's also removing the instances with outlier values, if that's an option.

Comment: RandomScaler does outlier treatment with IRQ.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of other options:

- Set a threshold and remove all values larger than the threshold.
- Apply [RobustScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing) which removes the median and scales the data according to the quantile range.
- Apply [QuantileTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html) which transforms the feature to follow a uniform or a normal distribution.